# Rhomobile supports graphics?

Tags: ruby, mobile, mobile-phones, rhomobile

Does the rhomobile support drawing with 2-d(3-d) graphics or is the graphic capabilities limited to static images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on the Rhomobile google group (http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile).  We don't support this now mostly for conserving space.  Pointed you to instructions for adding libraries on the Rhomobile wiki. Its not a big deal to add and we would do so if it seemed required by majority of developers.